# The limit of the function $(1-2\cos(x))/(\pi-3x)$ as $x\to\pi/3$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How to find the limit of the function $$\lim_{x\to\pi/3}\frac{1-2\cos(x)}{\pi-3x}$$
i don't know how to prove it. help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Do you want parentheses surrounding $\pi-3x$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide some context for this problem with an [edit]. Where does this problem come from? What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far, and where did that not succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $y:=\frac{\pi}{3}-x$,$$\cos x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-y\right)=\frac12(\cos y+\sqrt{3}\sin y)\implies\frac{1-2\cos x}{\pi-3x}=\frac{1-\cos y}{3y}-\frac{\sqrt{3}\sin y}{3y}.$$The limit is thus $0-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.(You could get it quicker with [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).)

Comment: thank you, i know the L'Hôpital's rule but i cant used it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{1- 2 \cos x}{\pi - 3x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{2 \sin x}{-3} =-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},$$ by L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

$$F=\dfrac23\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi3}\dfrac{\cos\dfrac\pi3-\cos x}{\dfrac\pi3-x}$$

Method $\#1:$

$$F=\dfrac23\cdot\dfrac{d(\cos x)}{dx}_{\text{at }x=\dfrac\pi3}=?$$

Method $\#2:$

Apply http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html $$\cos C-\cos D$$

and then [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Actually this is how the derivative of cosine has been calculated